# Full file path of an excel macro

Tags: python, excel, vba

I am trying to reference an excel macro using my python code, and I want to know the full filepath of the macro itself. The macro is called 'Highlight' and is stored in the personal workbook I have tried this so far:

```
C:\\Users\\Jack1\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Excel\\XLSTART\\PERSONAL.XLSB!Module2.Highlight
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know the full filepath of the macro itself

According to sources like https://bettersolutions.com/excel/macros/personal-xlsb.htm or https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/679412-where-are-macros-saved.html the location of the Macro should be:

```
C:\Users\your_user_id\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART
```

In this directory **the following syntax** can be looked after:

```
excelsheet_name.xlsm!modulename.macroname
```

Therefore the full path to your macro would be:

```
C:\Users\your_user_id\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\excelsheet_name.xlsm!modulename.macroname
```